# Creating my own proxy server

Tags: transparent-proxy

I have a remote machine which needs to serve as a proxy server (http), aswell as an http server.

The part of the http server is taken care of and is working, but as far as setting proxy server - I've never done so.

Every where I looked, I see php based web proxies, I want to create a transparent proxy, to be used in, let's say firefox.

Any leads?

Comment: [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) is what you need. It runs even in Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -- http://www.squid-cache.org/

The site is well documented and you will find a lot of resources online.

Comment: If for any reason squid does not match your needs, you might want to look at privoxy or tinyproxy.